# How can I prevent a java 1.4 project from using 1.5/1.6 specific API?

Tags: java, eclipse-3.5

Is there any way to restrict a java project configured with 1.4 compiler compliance level from using 1.5/1.6 specific API where the system is playing with 1.6 JRE?

Setting only 1.4 compiler compliance level on my project does not warn me from using especially 1.5/1.6 specific `java.lang.String` methods.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you're also using an 1.4 JRE system library in your project. The 1.4 compiler settings change the features which will be written into the class files, it doesn't restrict what you can see from the libraries in your project.

Open the properties for your project and check what you find under "Java Build Path" -> "Libraries" -> "JRE System Library". Click "Edit" to change or add new Java versions.

Comment: So, there is no way to dictate the compiler to throw error/warning for using 1.5/1.6 APIs with the JRE 1.6 System library included in the 1.4 project's classpath?

Comment: Of course not. From the view of the compiler, rt.jar is just another JAR on the classpath. It doesn't "know" that the classes in there mean something special to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the safest (and perhaps the simplest) way is to *compile* using a JDK 1.4, and *run* using a JRE 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the `rt.jar` from a 1.4 JRE (for instance by having the 1.4 JRE installed). If using `javac` use the following options:

```
 javac -source 1.4 -target 1.4 -bootclasspath /path/to/j2se1.4/lib/rt.jar [...]
```

Using `javac` from a later JRE means that it should have fewer bugs for old source, although it may not necessarily be entirely "bug compatible".

You might also want to use `-Djava.ext.dirs=directories` and `-Djava.endorsed.dirs`, but putting things in those directories is generally a bad idea.

Note: Even 1.5 has finished its End Of Service Life period. Get with 1.6! (Or buy one of our excellent Java for Business contracts...)

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is to remove those JDKs/JREs, which you don't want to use, from Eclipse's settings. In your case that would be 1.5 and 1.6.

To do this, go to Windows->Preferences and then type "JRE" in the top left hand side.

I would also check which JRE Eclipse in launched in and maybe edit your eclipse.ini.